# Problem seems too easy. Is there a trap? Show that $f(1-f)=0$ almost everywhere...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, almost-everywhere, measurable-functions

So this is a problem I found on a qualifying exam and it has been nagging at me for some a while. It seems overly easy.

> Assume that $f$ is a nonnegative function on $[0,1]$ and \begin{align}
> \int_{[0,1]}f\,dx=\int_{[0,1]}f^2\,dx=\int_{[0,1]}f^3\,dx.
> \end{align}
>   Show that $f(1-f)=0$ almost everywhere.

I assume that the difficulty may lay in the part "almost everywhere", but I don't think it's the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it's not true if you leave out the integral of $f^3$. So it can't be that trivial.

Comment: Right. I noticed that the integral of $f^3$ was necessary because otherwise, one can find a few counterexamples.

Comment: So what _is_ your super-obvious proof?

Comment: My idea of a proof would be just consider 
$$\int f^3-f^2=\int f^2-f=0$$ and then I can just apply Theorem 1.39 from Rudin's Real and Complex.

Maybe I'm making a big mistake with this idea, but that's what first came to mind.

Comment: Hint: $\int_{[0,1]} f (1-f)^2 \; dx = 0$.

Comment: @Darel: the problem with your approach is that you have no information about the sign of neither $f^3-f^2$ nor $f^2-f$.

Comment: @AlessioDV Okay so with the hint given and what you just pointed out, I think I get the problem a little better.
What I'm getting at with the hint is that $f(1-f)^2$ ensures that the function is nonnegative and I can actually apply the theorem without trouble. Then since $f(1-f)^2=0$ a.e. it is easy to see that $f(1-f)=0$ a.e.
That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: You've got it. It is that simple - once you spot it.

Comment: Haha! So I actually got that part. I guess impostor syndrome doesn't have this one against me.